# Xarray to NetCDF with transform applied

Tags: netcdf, rioxarray

I have a process that uses rioxarray to crop GeoTIFFs and create a nice xarray dataset. This works well. When I export to new GeoTIFFs they are perfect, coordinates and data are fine. When I try to export to a NetCDF file, despite linking spatial_ref and grid_mapping attributes I cannot get it to open in QGIS with the correct coordinate alignment. Could you suggesting something?

This is what QGIS throws up every time.

```
This layer appears to have no projection specification. By default, this layer will now have its projection set to that of the project, but you may override this by selecting a different projection below.
```

The current output file is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_DK8en0KHgqVx2M_aojMWVGkBOClMQnD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show the script? What is the output of `rioxarray.show_versions()`?

Comment: Have you read this? https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/crs_management.html